# Importing Contacts Framework in xcode7 , Swift2

Tags: frameworks, swift2, ios9, xcode7-beta4

Im trying to import contacts framework to my xcode7 , I have added the contacts framework from the build phases and I have declared

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
```

but it shows error saying `/Users/anonymous/Desktop/Contacts/Contacts/ViewController.swift:10:8: Cannot import module being compiled`

Comment: I suspect you gave the project name as "Contacts"?

Comment: yup i was testing this new framework

Comment: Yes try giving some different project name say"MyContactsDemo". it should work.

Comment: Ok but thats limited right? I mean What if I want to name a project and that happens to be some kind a name of one of the frameworks and then I cant use that framework in project?

Comment: please answer in answer box so that I can accept it and upvote it

Comment: what you suggested workd please put it in answer box so I can accept it

Comment: As like tokens are not accepted as ivars. i would compiler error should be more meaningful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes try giving some different project name say"MyContactsDemo". it should work.

Note:posted in answer block as suggested by the person who questioned.

Answer (score 1):

If your framework being embedded or linked against has the same name as your product/target... you will run into this issue with swift 2 & xcode 7 it seems. There are fixes mentioned above, but I'm adding this just to spell the problem out.